# Android Studio, cant add a button to viewpager

Tags: android, android-studio, button

Im totally new to android studio and tried creating a simple app. When creating the project, I chose "Tabbed Activity" which is working as intended.
But when I go to the Design manager and add a button, it is not possible to move it using the mouse because it disappears as soon as I try to move it.
As said, Im totally new to this and written/youtube guides didn't help me either.
Feel free to ask for any information if you need it.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
This is my activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.RiseUpdates.AppBarOverlay"
        android:background="@color/light_gray">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:minHeight="?actionBarSize"
            android:padding="@dimen/appbar_padding"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title" />

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/rise_orange"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/white"
            app:tabBackground="@color/light_gray" />
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/dark_gray"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Provide your XML.

Comment: Added it @Yegorf

Comment: I can't see any button in the XML :)

Comment: Sorry, fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Your ViewPager have attributes:

```
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

It means, that it takes all space in your CoordinatorLayout. And as the result, you button is hided under the ViewPager.

Comment: And yet this does not solve my issue. Its fine if I place the button in the center, bottom, top etc using an XML, but as soon as I try to move it using the mouse it disappears. (And android studio's animation shows that its being moved to the top left where it definitely isnt).

What else could I type into `android:layout_height` and `android:layout_width`?

Comment: "top left where it definitely isnt" - it is. By default if the view not atached to something, it placing in the (0,0) - top left angle.

Comment: Add android:layout_gravity="center" to your's button and it will be placed in the middle of the screen. P.s. android developers dont use mouse to edit views, they change views attributes in xml ;)

Comment: This solution works, but then the button is on top of everything, meaning it doesn't scroll like e.g. text on different pages does. Is there a solution for that?

Comment: Because you setted it in the center so it is always in the center:) And this is normal for CoordinatorLayout. You can add for example LinearLayout with vertical orientation and match_parent height and width and place you Pager and Button inside it. You should read about general Android Layouts.

Comment: Thank you, as said I have nearly no experience with Android Studio. Will read a bit about different layouts, thanks again for your help!